# Adding a classifier to a custom OutputWindow pane

Tags: visual-studio-sdk

Basically, is it possible to add a classifier to a custom OutputWindow pane?

I can add a new pane to the output window with the following code:

```
      IVsOutputWindow outputWindow = null;
    outputWindow = ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsOutputWindow)) as IVsOutputWindow;
    if (outputWindow.CreatePane(ref GuidList.guidDebugOutputFilteredPane, "FilteredOutput", 1, 1) == Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSConstants.S_OK)
    {
        if (outputWindow.GetPane(ref GuidList.guidDebugOutputFilteredPane, out filteredPane) == Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSConstants.S_OK)
        {
            filteredPane.OutputString("Created filtered pane. Need to add a classifier...");
        }
    }
```

But I'm at a loss as to how to add a classifier to it. I've added a classifier to the Debug pane of the Output window and I wanted to do some reformatting and filtering before displaying in the FilteredOutput pane with some additional syntax colouring.

I've create a FilteredOutput classifier with it's own ContentTypeDefinition (from MSDN):

```
  internal sealed class Components
{
    [Export]
    [Name("FilteredOutput")]
    [BaseDefinition("Output")]
    internal static ContentTypeDefinition FilteredOutputContentTypeDefinition;
}
```

I then used this to create a new IClassiferProvider:

```
  [ContentType("FilteredOutput")]
[Export(typeof(IClassifierProvider))]
public class FilteredOutputClassifierProvider : IClassifierProvider
{
    [Import]
    internal IClassificationTypeRegistryService ClassificationRegistry;
    public static FilteredOutputClassifier FilteredOutputClassifier { get; private set; }
    public IClassifier GetClassifier(ITextBuffer textBuffer)
    {
        return FilteredOutputClassifier ?? (FilteredOutputClassifier = new FilteredOutputClassifier(ClassificationRegistry));
    }
}
```

`GetClassifier()` is getting called for DebugOutput, but doesn't get called for FilteredOutput. Is this even feasible using a VSPackage type extension? This is in VS2013 using the latest VSSDK.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by accident whilst digging through the docs; use `CreatePane2()` from the `IVsOutputWindow3` interface, which allows you to specify a content type by name. Something like:

> ```
> IVsOutputWindow outputWindow = null;
> IVsOutputWindow3 outputWindow3 = null;
> outputWindow = ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsOutputWindow)) as IVsOutputWindow;
> outputWindow3 = ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsOutputWindow)) as IVsOutputWindow3;
> if (outputWindow3.CreatePane2(ref GuidList.guidDebugOutputFilteredPane, "Filtered Output", 1, 1, "FilteredOutput", PredefinedTextViewRoles.Debuggable) == Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSConstants.S_OK)
> {
>     if (outputWindow.GetPane(ref GuidList.guidDebugOutputFilteredPane, out filteredPane) == Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSConstants.S_OK)
>     {
>         filteredPane.OutputString("Created filtered pane. Need to add a classifier...");
>     }
> }
> ```